# How to always append a default frame at the end of a beamer presentation using a custom template?

Tags: beamer, automation

I'm using a custom beamer template in the corporate identity for my companies presentations (by having a class `.cls` file that loads the beamer class, all packages and sets all the beamer options). In the end of each presentation there always has to be the same "Thank you" style frame. I'd like to unify the process so that on every beamer PDF the default last page gets appended by the class code automatically and must not be copy-pasted to every single presentation.

How can I achieve this? I'm using LuaLaTeX if this is of any relevance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like a job for `\AtEndDocument{...}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\AtEndDocument{%
    \begin{frame}
        Thanks!
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. :) Sometimes the most obvious doesn't comes to ones mind....